# lubunto error compiling code

Tags: java, linux, javac

recently installed lubunto inside a VM and installed jre and jdk openjdk-9

Now I am just testing the javac compiler but it is not compiling my program, the program is very simple (literally hello world) so I am not sure if it is me being incredibly stupid for if the JDK is in error

Here is my program:

```
public class Test {
      public static void main (String[] args) {
           System.out.println("this is a test");
      }
}
```

The error I receive is: 
[image]

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,

I had to use sudo javac as i need root access to do anything
frustrating but sorted